# WordPress WooCommerce - Print Invoice for Customers - Access denied

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, invoices

I'm completely new to WordPress and I am trying to set up a simple store. It works fine, but I want my customers to be able to view the invoice right away from their orders. I downloaded the **WooCommerce Print Invoices & Delivery Notes** plugin, but it only allows *me* to print the invoice, not the customer. Therefore, I modified the WooCommerce `/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php` file to include a button that generates the invoice:

```
/* USERCONTENT */
if ( $order->status == 'completed' ) {
    $actions['invoice'] = array(
        'url' => wp_nonce_url( '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=generate_print_content&template_type=invoice&order_id=' . $order->id , 'generate_print_content' ),
        'name' => __( 'Invoice', 'woocommerce' )
    );
}
/* ENDUSERCONTENT */
```

This works when I view my orders. I assigned a test order to myself:

[image]

Clicking the *Invoice* button opens the invoice generated by the **WooCommerce Print Invoices & Delivery Notes** Plugin, which is *exactly what I want*. But it does not work for my customers. They see a webpage with the message "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." instead.

My assumption is that it has to do with the fact that it is accessing `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Is there another `~-ajax.php` that I can invoke the GET on and users will have access to?

Answer (score 2):

This call is tied to "wp_ajax_" type of action which, in general, allows all logged in users to access it, so that is fine. You can read more about Ajax in WordPress plugins [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

You may wish to open `/classes/class-wcdn-print.php` and comment out these two blocks:

```
            if( !is_admin() ) {
                wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
            }

            if( !current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce_orders' ) && !current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) {
                wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
            }
```

Or you can give [WooCommerce PDF Invoice](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-pdf-invoice/5951088?ref=RightPress) plugin a try - invoices will be available for both administrators and customers plus it attaches invoices to emails (disclosure: I'm the author).